# Download remote pictures from XNA (executed under Windows Phone)

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

Is there any way to load a remote picture from XNA? I have the http URL. Thanks.

JB

Answer (score 1):

You can use libs from silverlight.

Something like this.

```
    Texture2D texture;

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
       texture = Texture2D.FromStream(gd.GraphicsDevice, stream); 
    }
```

[Read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: could you give a more precise example please?